# Android: How to handle the result of WorkManager Rx?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, android-workmanager

I am developing an Android app using the WorkManager (Android Jetpack) with Rx.
Below is the Worker class.

```
class ImageRxWorker(
    appContext: Context,
    private val workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : RxWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override fun createWork(): Single<Result> = Single.create<Result> { emitter -

        // do the job

        emitter.onSuccess(Result.success())
    }

}
```

It works fine, there is no problem.
But what I want to know is how can I handle the result?

```
class MainPresenter(
    private val view: MainActivity,
    private val workManager: WorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance()
) : MainContract.Presenter {

    override fun startWork(): Completable {
        view.showToastMessage(R.string.worker_started)

        return Completable.create { emitter ->
            val uploadWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ImageRxWorker>().build()
            workManager.enqueue(uploadWorkRequest)
            emitter.onComplete() // This is not exit immediately.
        }
    }

}
```

I found "addListener", "result", but I don't know how to use them.
And I tried to googling but I cannot find any good reference.
Somebody help me!

---

I think... I found one of the solutions.

**It WORKS!!!**

But... it is... very ugly... and not smart...

(In my app, I don't use LiveData.)

```
    override fun startWork(): Completable {
        view.showToastMessage(R.string.worker_started)

        return Completable.create { emitter ->
            Log.d(TAG, "[WM][Presenter] startWork - start")
            val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ImageRxWorker>()
                .setInputData(workDataOf("TIME" to 1000L))
                .build()

            workManager.enqueue(workRequest)

            while (workManager.getWorkInfoById(workRequest.id).get().state != WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                // Should I really polling?
                Thread.sleep(1000)
                Log.d(TAG, "[WM][Presenter] not yet......")
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "[WM][Presenter] complete")
            emitter.onComplete()
        }
    }
```

---

Wow, here is the third code that was written by "User One"'s answer.
It works fine and looks better than the second code.
Because my app doesn't use 'LiveData', I cannot ensure that whether this code is valid.

In the "observeForever", I am calling "cancelWorkById" after the Worker is done.
Is it correct?

```
    override fun startWork(): Completable {
        view.showToastMessage(R.string.worker_started)

        return Completable.create { emitter ->
            Log.d(TAG, "[WM][Presenter] startWork - start")
            val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ImageRxWorker>()
                .setInputData(workDataOf("TIME" to 1000L))
                .build()

            workManager.enqueue(workRequest)

            workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.id).observeForever { workInfo ->
                workInfo?.outputData?.getString("key")?.let { data ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "[WM][Presenter] startWork - complete: $data")
                    emitter.onComplete()
                    workManager.cancelWorkById(workRequest.id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Method you use getWorkInfoById return a ListenableFuture, and this one return a LiveData :

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(java.util.UUID)

Instead of your while loop, You can simply observe The Work Status by observing the LiveData returned by getWorkInfoByIdLiveData() and then call emitter.onComplete() once it's trigerred, but you have no LifeCycle here in your presenter so you should use observeForever() and take care of removing the Observer,

Here is an example :

```
workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.id)
 .observeForever(object : Observer<WorkInfo> {
        override fun onChanged(workInfo : WorkInfo?) {
           if(workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {
             ////The Work result is a Success
            }
            /* Here We remove the Observer if Not needed anymore
                 'this' here = the Observer */
         workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.id)
          .removeObserver(this) 
        }
```

Or simply use the ListenableFuture returned by getWorkInfoById() to get a CallBack

Comment: Thank you, I edit the question with new code that guided by you. I don't know how can I "removing the observer". So I wrote the "cancelWorkById" in the "observeForever". Could you tell me Is it fine?

Comment: If you go for the LiveData way, then first declare an Observer for example myObserver then call getWorkInfoByIdLiveData().observeForever(myObserver) then when it's trigerred if you don't need it anymore call getWorkInfosByIdLiveData.removeObserver(myObserver)

Comment: And yes using this LiveData is valid, also, calling cancelWorkById() will cancel your work not related with the LiveData, this is not what you want right ? Replace with removeObserver as i've said, and check the data parameter when it's trigerred, it should maybe contains a Status(Sucess etc..)

Comment: Hmm... I got the point, but I still don't know where can I call the "removeObserver". Could you give me more guide please?...